# React hooks - remove from react-router location state when we refresh page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

When I am entering one page of the app I pass data through location state using react-router. Then I access it via `location.state.myDataObject`. When I refresh the page it is still there, while I would like it to be empty. Here's what I've try to use:

```
  const resetLocation = () => {
    history.replace({
      ...location,
      state: undefined,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', resetLocation);
  }, []);
```

Or adding it to `unmount` action within `useEffect` but I guess it is not called when refreshing the page:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanLocationState() {
      history.replace({
        ...this.props.location,
        state: undefined,
      });
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: nope, i didn't.

Comment: if can display sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) .it's great.

Comment: could you share any additional react router configuration you have, because with the default behaviour seems to work fine, it resets the state when you refresh the page, you can check it out in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/state-react-router-5-1tlzb the `Schedule` link sets the state

Comment: Maybe your code still goes through the entire flow when you refresh? Then you're not refreshing the page, but running the apllication from the start index.js -> page1 (maybe some other prop navigates automatically to page 2) -> page2. Then it could be the reason why your props are always set. 

I believe react-router should not be able to save any data automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the desired behavior of react router. If you want to reset the state then you need to do something like

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const replaceHistory = useCallback(() => {
    history.replace({ ...location, state: undefined });
  }, [history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => replaceHistory);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", replaceHistory);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-4f8edw?file=components/Home.js)

Answer (score 0):

How about you try the contrary? Store the value on component did mound and delete it from the location. I'm not sure that this is the prettiest solution, but i guess it's the easiest

```js
const [state,setState]=useState();

useEffect(()=>{
  setState(location.state);
  location.state=undefined;
}, [location])
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the react-router will not save the history state after refresh the page so we need to know more about your code to really solve this issue. However, if the state do save, byour first attempt seem to have some flaw by using the history and location of window instead from the props.

```
function Page(props){

  useEffect(() => {
    const unloadFunc = () => {
      //use the history and the location from the props instead of window
      props.history.replace({
        ...props.location,
        state: undefined,
      });
    }
    window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload',unloadFunc);
    return ()=>{
        window.removeEventListener('onbeforeunload' unloadFunc);     
      //make history and location as the dependencies of the hook
  }, [props.history, props.location]);

  return <div></div>
}
```

Comment: you forgot to remove the listener and this will trigger on any history or location change

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function replaceHistory(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      delete e.returnValue;
    }

    history.replace({ ...history.location, state: undefined });
  }

  console.log("history", history.location);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => replaceHistory);
    return () => {
      // Reset Location state if we leave this page
      replaceHistory();
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", replaceHistory);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

[CodesandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clear-react-router-state-forked-i8ug5)